# How to set `contract` as input argument

Tags: contract, ligo, testing, dry-run

I have a method `Token_metadata_registry` which takes `contract(address)` as input parameter and I would like to call that method from `ligo dry-run`. How do I do that?

```
 ligo dry-run contracts/main/fa2.ligo --syntax pascaligo --sender="<address>" main 'Token_metadata_registry( <contract> )'
```

How do I specify `<contract>`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Testing contract to contract calls should be done by programming and deploying wrapper contracts solely designed for testing the contract-to-contract endpoints.